# Dispatcher::applyFilter _callable - passing message to redirected page

Tags: aop, lithium

I followed the tutorial in http://li3.me/docs/manual/lithium-basics/filters.wiki

At the end of the tutorial, if the user is unauthorized, then they get redirected to a login page.

My question: I want to know how to display a message on the login page to explain why they got redirected.

I'm assuming I have to pass my message into the closure, but I'm not sure what to do in the closure itself.

Comment: Learn how HTTP redirection works first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx

Answer (score 4):

If you need to persist data between 2 requests, write to the [Session](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/storage/Session).

In your case, before redirecting the user to a new location (login page), write to the Session a message (usually just called flash messages).

```
Session::write('Flash.auth', array('message' => '...'), array('name' => 'default'))
```

Then on your views, check if the Session is not empty, to display it or not.

```
Session::read('Flash.auth', array('name' => 'default'))
```

Since you'll need to do that in many parts of your application, take a look to [li3_flash_message](https://github.com/michaelhue/li3_flash_message) plugin, or roll your own

Comment: I was hoping I could pass it directly to the next page since I'm initiating the redirect myself. Or at least, that's what the closure is looking like its doing to me. I'm not very strong in terms of the plumbing in these things.

Comment: redirect() don't take a flash message param by default, but it's easily extensible to allow you pass it directly from redirect() with something like $this->redirect('/', array('error' => "I'm sorry, I can't seem to find your record.")); --- Come to IRC if you need help for doing that

Comment: if the session is the more natural thing to do, the cleanest, you can use anything else from a cookie to the query string.